# Showing MajorTickMark values in c# chart

Tags: c#, plot, charts

here is my chart and I set  MajorTickMark Intervals with this line.

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorTickMark.Interval = 20;
```

[image]

I can see the MajorTickMark with interval 20 as I set but I want to see not only 200, 400, 600 .. but also the values of each MajorTickMark like 20, 40, 60, 80..

Which parameter should I change to show all MajorTickMark values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are happy with the `AxisX.MajorTickMark.Interval` you can get labels for each like this by syn'ching the `Axis.Interval` with it:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorTickMark.Interval;
```

It will get a bit crowded along your axis..:

[image]